# Adding all output of a variable in liquid

Tags: variables, liquid

This is a variable who outputs item quantity for a single product order,

```
`{{item.qty}}`

output= product 9 = 2pcs
```

and the output is pretty normal,
But when multiple products ordered it outputs every quantity of each product ordered,

```
Product 1 = 2pcs
product 2 = 7pcs
product 3 = 9pcs
```

how to go about this adding every output in one single total?

Comment: Can you make your question clearer? I do not understand it.

Comment: {% cycle {{item.qty}} %}//output 1pc, 1pc
this is my code to pull every item quantity, just want to know how can I add every output that it throws,

Answer (score 0):

If your front matter is like this:

```
---
title: Product 1
qty: 3
---
```

Your layout should be like this:

```
{% assign siteproducts = site.products | sort: 'qty' %}
{% for item in siteproducts %}

  {{ title }} = {{ qty }}pcs

{% endfor %}
```